# What am I missing with CSS grid here? Why the horizontal scroll bar

Tags: html, css

[Horizontal Scroll Bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZHGC.png)

Question: 1

Why is there a horizontal scroll bar on the #main-header .content-container .videos. I can get rid of it with overflow-x: hidden on the body but dont understand why its there in the first place.

```
/* Background and Left Side */

#main-header {
    background: #fff;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
}

#main-header .content-container .social {
    display: flex;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 10vw;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    align-items: center;
}

#main-header .content-container .social i {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    color: #333;
}

#main-header .content-container .social a {
    color: #333;
}

#main-header .content-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2,1fr);
}

/* Right Side */

#main-header .content-container .videos {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 90vw;
    background: #f4f4f4;
}

#main-header .content-container img {
    width: 330px;
    height: 200px;
}

#main-header .content-container .videos .grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3,1fr);
}

#main-header .content-container .videos .contain-video {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}


#main-header .content-container .videos .contain-video .text-wrap {
    padding: 1rem 1rem;
    width: 330px;
}
```

Question 2: I don't understand why I am only seeing the repeat(2,1fr) I have the min-width and max-width all set. I know the repeat(2,1fr) comes after but I have the max-width set for that.

```
/* MEDIA 1230 */

@media (min-width:886px) and (max-width:1250px) {


/* Middle */

#main-nav .content-container .middle {
    width: 60%;
}

#main-nav .content-container .middle input {
    width: 55%;
    margin-left: 4rem;
}

/* Right Side */

#main-nav .content-container .right-side {
    width: 45%;
}

#main-header .content-container .videos .grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3,1fr);
}

}

/* 875PX */

@media(min-width:701px) and (max-width:885px) {

/* Left Side */

.content-container .left-side img {
height: 60px;
width: 120px;
}

/* MIDDLE */

#main-nav .content-container .middle {
    width: 80%;
}

#main-nav .content-container .middle input {
    width: 50%;
    margin-left: 2rem;
}

#main-nav .content-container .middle a {
    margin-right: 3rem;
    padding: 0.6rem 1.2rem;

}

/* Right Side */

#main-nav .content-container .right-side {
    width: 55%;
}

#main-nav .content-container .right-side .fas {
    margin-right: 0.5rem;
}

#main-nav .content-container .right-side a {
    padding: 0.65rem 0.45rem;
    font-size: 1rem;
}
}

/* Heading - Right Side */
#main-header .content-container .videos .grid-container {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2,1fr);
}
```

HTML :

```
<!-- Header -->

   <header id="main-header">
    <div class="content-container">
        <div class="social">
            <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-user-circle"></i>Home</a>
            <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-user-circle"></i>Trending</a>
            <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-user-circle"></i>Subscriptions</a>
            <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-user-circle"></i>Library</a>
            <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-user-circle"></i>History</a>
        </div>
        <div class="videos py-2">
            <h2>Recommended</h2>
                    <div class="grid-container">

                        <div class="contain-video">
                            <img src="./img/blink182feature_header.jpg" alt="blink">
                            <div class="text-wrap">
                                <h4>Mix - Blink 182 - Official Video</h4>
                                <h6>Blink 182, Taking Back Sunday and more</h6>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="contain-video">
                            <img src="./img/blink182feature_header.jpg" alt="blink">
                            <div class="text-wrap">
                                <h4>Mix - Blink 182 - Official Video</h4>
                                <h6>Blink 182, Taking Back Sunday and more</h6>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="contain-video">
                            <img src="./img/blink182feature_header.jpg" alt="blink">
                            <div class="text-wrap">
                                <h4>Mix - Blink 182 - Official Video</h4>
                                <h6>Blink 182, Taking Back Sunday and more</h6>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="contain-video">
                            <img src="./img/blink182feature_header.jpg" alt="blink">
                            <div class="text-wrap">
                                <h4>Mix - Blink 182 - Official Video</h4>
                                <h6>Blink 182, Taking Back Sunday and more</h6>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="contain-video">
                            <img src="./img/blink182feature_header.jpg" alt="blink">
                            <div class="text-wrap">
                                <h4>Mix - Blink 182 - Official Video</h4>
                                <h6>Blink 182, Taking Back Sunday and more</h6>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="contain-video">
                            <img src="./img/blink182feature_header.jpg" 
alt="blink">
                            <div class="text-wrap">
                                <h4>Mix - Blink 182 - Official Video</h4>
                                <h6>Blink 182, Taking Back Sunday and more</h6>
                            </div>
                        </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
   </header>
```

[horizontal scroll still there after changed .videos width: 75vw](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VCX97.png)

Comment: add your html structure to snippet .. its will help to understand the problem.

Comment: html structure needed for proper help.
but I suggest you try removing `width: 100vw;` from #main-header

Comment: **Needs more focus.** This question currently includes multiple questions in one. It should focus on one problem only. [ask]

Comment: HTML structure added.

Comment: Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You should reduce the width of

```
#main-header .content-container .videos
{
height: 100vh;
width: 75vw;
background: #f4f4f4;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately no dice with that. It just makes the sidebar bigger for some reason. Horizontal scroll bar still intact. Also don't know why the media queries aren't working properly either.